# Why is `Eq a` constraint required for the solution using `elem`?

Tags: haskell

I was solving the following exercise from the [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/):

```
-- >>> flipMaybe [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3]
-- Just [1, 2, 3]
-- >>> flipMaybe [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
-- Nothing

flipMaybe :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
flipMaybe = undefined
```

First I tried using `elem`,

```
flipMaybeWithElem :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
flipMaybeWithElem ms
  | Nothing `elem` ms = Nothing
  | otherwise         = Just (catMaybes ms)
```

but I got the error message:

```
misc.hs:86:5: error:
    • No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘elem’
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            flipMaybe2 :: forall a. [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
    • In the expression: Nothing `elem` ms
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for ‘flipMaybe2’:
        Nothing `elem` ms
      In an equation for ‘flipMaybe2’:
          flipMaybe2 ms
            | Nothing `elem` ms = Nothing
            | otherwise = Just (catMaybes ms)
   |
86 |   | Nothing `elem` ms = Nothing
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand that I should just add the `Eq a =>` constraint to the function signature, but I was trying to stay true to the provided function stub. So I reused previous functions, and it did work:

```
flipMaybe :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
flipMaybe ms =
  case (filter isNothing ms) of
    [] -> Just (catMaybes ms)
    _  -> Nothing
```

The helper functions used:

```
isNothing :: Maybe a -> Bool
isNothing Nothing = True
isNothing _       = False

mayybee :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
mayybee b _ Nothing = b
mayybee b f (Just a) = f a

fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
fromMaybe a maybe = mayybee a id maybe

catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
catMaybes xs = map (fromMaybe undefined) (filter isJust xs)
```

---

So **why doesn't the first solution with `elem` work without the type constraints?**

Is it simply because `filter` and `isNothing` have no constraints on the type variables and `elem` has? (Also with `isNothing` the type variable never even comes into play because it is ignored.)

```
> :t filter               
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

> :t isNothing                              
isNothing :: Maybe a -> Bool                               

> :t elem
elem :: (Eq a, Foldable t) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

`Maybe` has an `Eq` instance, but I guess the compiler does not know anything about `a`, right?

Comment: I accepted Silvio Mayolo's answer because it also included `Maybe`'s `Eq` instance that I missed, but thank you Daniel Wagner for the prompt reassurance!

Comment: Does Haskell's laziness come into play in `isNothing`? Because its type signature does mention `Maybe a`, but I assume that because it is never matched, the compiler will ignore it.

Comment: Laziness is always in play. But I'm not sure I understood your question yet; what are the two "it"s in "I assume that because it is never matched, the compiler will ignore it"?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity; I think I am starting to overthinking it. What I meant is that `isNothing`'s type signature mentions `Maybe a`, but the compiler won't throw an error because type variable `a` is never matched (instantiated?).

Comment: Don't confuse the type level with the term level. `Nothing` is a perfectly suitable term, and its type is `Maybe a` regardless of what `a` is. There is no conflict between the statements "this term contains no values of type `a`" and "this term has a type which mentions `a`".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it simply because `filter` and `isNothing` have no constraints on the type variables and `elem` has? (Also with `isNothing` the type variable never even comes into play because it is ignored.)

You've hit the nail on the head here. `elem`, *in general*, will only work if `Eq a` is satisfied. You're trying to use it on `[Maybe a]`, and `Maybe a` has the following `Eq` instance.

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) where
    ...
```

So `elem` looks at your `Maybe a` and says "I need this to be `Eq`". It sees the above instance and says "for `Maybe a` to satisfy `Eq`, `a` must satisfy `Eq`, and I don't know `Eq a`". Now, in your *particular* case, you only compare against `Nothing`, so the `Eq a` instance is never actually used. But the compiler doesn't have enough information to know this; it just knows that `elem` needs `Eq a`, and you don't provide it with that constraint.

In order to get this function to work without `Eq`, you need to do it the way you already did it, either with explicit recursion or with `filter` and `isNothing`. In short, I think you've already figured out the answer, and I'm just reiterating the things you've already said.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it simply because `filter` and `isNothing` have no constraints on the type variables and `elem` has? (Also with `isNothing` the type variable never even comes into play because it is ignored.)

Correct, you nailed it here.

> `Maybe` has an `Eq` instance, but I guess the compiler does not know anything about `a`, right?

Nailed it again.